# Extending Classes with new properties without overriding the main constructor

Tags: coffeescript

Considering the usual `Person`class:

```
class Person
  constructor: (@firstName, @lastName) ->
  sayName: ->
     console.log "Hi, im #{@firstName} #{@lastName}"
```

I then want to extend this class with a new one, called `Employee` that has an additional property `position`:

```
class Employee extends Person
   constructor: (@position) ->
```

The problem with this is that im overriding the `Person`constructor, so my employees instances won't get the `firstName` and `lastName` variables.

What would be the best way to achieve this, without redefining the constructor function and inheriting those properties from the `Person` class?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to have happen here?  Do you want firstName and lastName to exist and be Null? To have them refer to some default value?  since you're only passing a single value to the constructor (apparently), its unclear what you want to see happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, well, you've overridden the *ability* to accept a first and last name in the constructor. So I'm guessing you want to accept the base classes constructor arguments as well as additional arguments?

Something like this could work with any number of arguments from the base class constructor.

```
class Person
  constructor: (@firstName, @lastName) ->
  sayName: ->
     console.log "Hi, im #{@firstName} #{@lastName}"

class Employee extends Person
   constructor: (args..., @position) -> super

dude = new Employee 'Shooty', 'McFace', 1
dude.sayName() # Hi, im Shooty McFace 
console.log "position: #{ dude.position }" # position: 1
```

[Working example here](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Person%0A%20%20constructor%3a%20%28@firstName,%20@lastName%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20sayName%3a%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20console.log%20%22Hi,%20im%20#%7B@firstName%7D%20#%7B@lastName%7D%22%0A%0Aclass%20Employee%20extends%20Person%0A%20%20%20constructor%3a%20%28args...,%20@position%29%20-%3E%20super%0A%0Adude%20=%20new%20Employee%20%27Shooty%27,%20%27McFace%27,%201%0Adude.sayName%28%29%0Aconsole.log%20%22position%3a%20#%7B%20dude.position%20%7D%22%0A)

Here we use a splat (the `...`) to soak up any arguments that we don't need to name. All these arguments get implicitly passed to `super` which is the base class constructor. The last argument will be the additional argument you want to capture.